# Is there an error in Wolfram integrator for determine $\int_{0}^{1}\ln{x}\ln{(-\ln{x})}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over 1+x^2}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln{x}\ln{(-\ln{x})}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over 1+x^2}=I=-0.468837...\tag1$$

Wolfram integrator gives a closed form $$I={\gamma_1(3/4)-\gamma_1(1/4)\over 16}+C(\gamma+\ln{4})\ne-0.468837...\tag2$$

But the closed form value doesn't match with the integral value.

Catalan's constant;$C=0.9156...$

$$\gamma_1(3/4)-\gamma_1(1/4)=\pi(\gamma+\ln{4})+2\pi\ln\left({\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot{\Gamma(3/4)\over \Gamma(1/4)}}\right)$$

Is there another mal-function in wolfram integrator software?

How can we evaluate the closed form for $(1)$?

Comment: Perhaps give a link to Wolfram Integrator?

Comment: Here is the link http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+lnxln(-lnx)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)dx,x%3D0+to+1

Comment: Maybe you must ask this question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). I [checked](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=numerical+integration+ln(x)*ln(-ln(x))%2F(1%2Bx%5E2),+x%3D0+to+1) and the two expressions are equivalent...

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a symbolic expression

Comment: The exponents in $\text{StieltjesGamma}^{(0,1)}(\ldots)$ mean that a derivative is involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let we set $x=e^{-t}$. Then we are looking for a closed form for

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-t} (-t \log t)\frac{dt}{1+e^{-2t}}\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \int_{0}^{+\infty}(-t\log t)e^{-(2n+1)t}\,dt$$
and by differentiation under the integral sign
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} (t \log t)e^{-(2n+1)t}\,dt = \left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{(2n+1)^{\alpha+1}}\right)\right|_{\alpha=1} $$
hence the previous integral equals
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{(\gamma-1)+\log(2n+1)}{(2n+1)^2}=(\gamma-1)K-\frac{1}{4}\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left[\zeta\left(\alpha,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(\alpha,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]\right|_{\alpha=2}. $$

The integral does not directly depend on the Stieltjes constants $\gamma_1(1/4)$ and $\gamma_1(3/4)$, but rather on $\gamma_1'(\alpha)=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\gamma_1(\alpha)$ at $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: It is also quite strange for Euler and Catalan constants to be involved in an integral together. I haven't see it before.